# yaml-cpp parsing strings

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Is it possible to parse YAML formatted strings with yaml-cpp?

There isn't a `YAML::Parser::Parser(std::string&)` constructor. (I'm getting a YAML string via libcurl from a http-server.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/):

```
std::string s = "name: YAML from libcurl";
std::stringstream ss(s);
YAML::Parser parser(ss);
```

Answer (score 8):

In the new version, you can parse a string directly (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial/)):

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::Load("[1, 2, 3]");
```